# "Record not found in table with primary key [NULL]" error in cakephp 3 association form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm stuck on how to save a BelongsToMany/Through association through the parent form.

I have a ProjectsTable that belongsToMany Characters through ProjectCharacters.
I have a CharactersTable that belongsToMany Projects through ProjectCharacters.

My projects/edit/# page contains a second form after the regular projects/edit form that looks like this:

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($project_character); ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('character_id', ['options' => $character_options]);
        echo $this->Form->hidden('project_id', ['value' => $project['id']]);
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Add Character')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

This is just a project id and character id that I want to create a new record for in ProjectCharacters. but when I press save, I get the following error:

```
 Record not found in table "projects" with primary key [NULL]
```

What do I need to do to save a ProjectCharacter association through this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your problem is here:

https://gist.github.com/sarahkeefe/a42d39efade836a675c8#file-projectscontroller-php-L156

You are trying to validate the ownership of a project for an action that does not receive any arguments (the add function). You need to conditionally execute that code or to always allow your `add()` action to your users.

In the future, you can look at the error page, it has  a stack trace, which is a list of functions that got called before your error happened. They usually indicate the place where your error can be found.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really stuck on this. How can I correctly send the project ID via the form so the ProjectCharacter object will save correctly? I tried adding a redirect if the project ID wasn't available, and that avoids the error but still doesn't save the ProjectCharacter object.

Comment: aha! it was as you described, except the issue was on line 85: I needed to use return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit/' . $id]); instead of only return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit'); Thanks!